# What is this board game called?

Tags: identify-this-game

My brother and I play this game using 8 white checkers and 8 black checkers on opposite sides of the board. We take turns flicking the checkers across the board to knock the opponent's checkers off the board. Once all the opponents checkers are gone, you win that round. We called this game "Chinese Checkers", but apparently Chinese Checkers is a different game using a hexagonal board rather than a square one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers . So, what is this game supposed to be called?

Comment: This appears to be a cross post that was migrated here and now is a duplicate.